# Why do we need to use ERD when we have class diagram?

Tags: class-diagram, erd

I don't understand what's the main reason: why do we use Erd when we can use a class diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Entity-relationship diagrams are used for conceptual modeling of information. It describes the business domain and the organization of state in an information system. It doesn't represent the storage and manipulation of state.

Class diagrams are used for modeling components of a system. Objects have state, but have behavior too. Class diagrams don't represent the organization of state inside objects, only the methods that can inspect or modify that state. They describe parts of the solution system rather than the problem domain.

Where it gets confusing is when people don't distinguish the business domain from the architecture of the information system. Systems built in this way usually fail to see the advantages of both data modeling and OOP.

As an analogy, compare a road map with an engineering diagram of a car.

Comment: Thanks Sir it really helped me out 
I hope i will get more information further too .

Answer (score 0):

Well in simplest possible words, ERDs are drawn for database designers in web-based projects to help them understand better. Class diagrams are designed for programmers.

ERDs layouts all the entities present in a system and relationship among them, whilst class diagrams are important in terms of programming point of view. They picture out which task is dependent on other.